# How to pass an element in list as an index to a list in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, data-structures

Given a sorted list `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` and a shuffled version of that list

```
a=[1,2,5,3,7,8,6,4]
```

I want to find how many steps each element has moved from its position relative to the sorted list (steps towards index 0 being positive, steps away from index 0 being negative) and store those step values in the respective index in a different list.

For the given input, the expected output is:

```
b=[0,0,-1,-4,2,-1,2,2]
```

Considering the value `3` (which is at index 2 in the sorted list), in the shuffled array it is at index 3, so it has taken -1 step, and hence `b[2] = -1`. Similarly for the value `8` (which is at index 7 in the sorted list), in the shuffled array it is at index 5, so it has taken +2 steps, and hence `b[7] = 2`.

This is what I have tried:

```
b=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
a=[1,2,5,3,7,8,6,4]
for x in range(len(a)):
   b[a[x]]=a[x]-(x+1)
```

I am getting an error with this code:

> IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Please help me understand this. Why can't I pass an integer from a list as an index to another list?

Comment: Not very intuitive how you determined `b`. Can you explain your process?

Comment: @smac89, here lets say the original order is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] and in a=[1,2,5,3,7,8,6,4] 5 is 3rd position so it took 2 steps forward. 4 is in 8th position so it has moved -4 steps. 1 and 2 remains same position so 0,0.like wise other numbers. 3 took -1 steps. 6 took -1 steps. 7 and 8 took 2 steps each.

Comment: That's why your example is confusing because it shows that 5 needs to move back 1 step, but actually it should be moving forward 2 steps

Comment: @smac89 Hope its clear now.. Can you please help with this?

Comment: Please correct the expected output first. Also how do you create the array `b`?

Comment: The number 8 in the list `a` is not a valid index in the list `b`. Indexes begin at 0, not 1, so the first index in `b` is 0 and the last index in `b` is 7, not 8.

Comment: @smac89, The expected output is correct and the list `b[]`in the for loop is the expected output.

Comment: I know `b` is a list, my question is can you include in your question how you are creating `b`. i.e. are you simply doing `b = []`?

Comment: @smac89 I have explained in in my first comment. It depends on the number of positions changed from its original state([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])  to final state [1,2,5,3,7,8,6,4].

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean, nor does it seem like you understand what I'm asking. See my answer and maybe that will help you understand what I mean by _how are you creating b?_

Comment: My doubt is why cant we pass a[2] or other values as index to b. Eg: b[a[2]]=10

Comment: b i took initially as `b=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`

Comment: How do you define the initial state? Python lists are zero indexed, so ``[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`` is not a list of indices (misses 0 and adds 8). If it is a list of arbitrary elements, what defines their natural order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the result you want with a simple comparison of the expected value at an array position with the index of that value in the `a` array. By iterating over the number of elements in `a`, we can generate the output array:

```
a = [1,2,5,3,7,8,6,4]
b = []
for x in range(len(a)):
    b.append(x - a.index(x+1))
print(b)
```

Output

```
[0, 0, -1, -4, 2, -1, 2, 2]
```

[Demo on rextester](https://rextester.com/DWG98840)

Answer (score 1):

The problem as you very well know is that there is an index error.

```
a=[1,2,5,3,7,8,6,4]
```

The above array has size = 8.

Now you create `b`:

```
b=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

The size of the list `b` is also 8.

In your for loop you are doing:

```
b[a[x]]
```

#### Pause...

If `x` is 5, then `a[x]` will be 8. However, there is no such thing as index 8 in list `b`, which only has up to index 7.

#### This is the problem.

You should change the code in your for-loop to:

```
b[a[x] - 1]=a[x]-(x+1)
```

I would suggest you change your loop to this:

```
for x, n in enumerate(a):
   b[n-1] = n-(x+1)
```

Comment: @SreeHarshaKOLI When you do `b[a[2]] = 10`, did you actually check what element in `b` changed? That should give you a clue why `b[8]` failed

Comment: Yeah i got it. Thank you for your time and patience. This is my first post in stackoverflow.  It means a lot. :)

Comment: @SreeHarshaKOLI You are welcome. If this has answered your question, please mark it as accepted. Have a nice day

Comment: enumerate can start counting from 1

Answer (score 1):

**Index starts from 0 to n-1**
,so in b=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] (having 8 elements) index will start from **0 to 7** and list 'a=[1,2,5,3,7,8,6,4]' contains numbers from 1-8 hence 8 is out of index.

corrected code:

```
b=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
a=[1,2,5,3,7,8,6,4]
for x in range(len(a)):
   b[a[x] - 1]=a[x]-(x + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding any indexing, nor unnecessary offsets, we can store the elements in a dictionary (the element as the key and its move as the value)

```
a=[1,2,5,3,7,8,6,4]

d = {v: v-e for e,v in enumerate(a, 1)}
b = [v for _, v in sorted(d.items())]
print(b)
```

produces

```
[0, 0, -1, -4, 2, -1, 2, 2]
```